# Is this comparison dummy?

Tags: c, md5, md5sum

In the [RFC1321](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt)

I notice this piece of code:

```
if ((context->count[0] += ((UINT4)inputLen << 3)) < ((UINT4)inputLen << 3))
    context->count[1]++;
context->count[1] += ((UINT4)inputLen >> 29);
```

I don't understand the comparison:

```
((UINT4)inputLen << 3)) < ((UINT4)inputLen << 3))
```

It is like it always returns 0, right?

Comment: 'cause you are erroneously evaluating the condition. Is comparing the result of `context->count[0] += ((UINT4)inputLen << 3)`  with `((UINT4)inputLen << 3)`

Comment: My mistake... Too many parenthesis

Comment: Lets not write `UINT4 u4 = inputLen << 3; context->count[0] += u4; if(context->count[0] < u4)`. Because why write good code when you can write rotten code?

Comment: No, not too many parentheses, for THAT code, you definitly should not use fewer. A little whitespace however might make it more readable.

Comment: @Yunnosch Note how my re-write has zero parenthesis, apart from the mandatory one in `if()`.

Comment: @Lundin I did see your code comment and liked it. I was referring to OPs original code. I would have even ticked your comment, if my personal feeling wasn't that it  has a slightly too sarcastic phrasing. Do not worry, it seems nowhere near flag worthy either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such comparison. Look how the parentheses are paired:

It is

```
(X < ((UINT4)inputLen << 3))
```

where `X` =

```
(context->count[0] += ((UINT4)inputLen << 3))
```